# sql search where clauses

Tags: java, sql-server

I want to search based on `siteid(integer)`, `refrenceno` and `oldrefrenceno` from `account(table)`, but my queries search only for `refrencno(varchar(15))` and `oldrefrenceno(varchar(50))`. It's showing nothing when the user enters `siteid` to search data.

```
Statement pst=null;
pst=ccn.createStatement();
String a=txt_search.getText();
String sql = "";
try {
    int s = Integer.parseInt(siteid.getText());
    sql ="select * from account WHERE siteid ="+s+" refrenceno='"+a+"' or oldrefrenceno='"+a+"' ";
}catch (Exception ex){
    sql ="select * from account WHERE refrenceno='"+a+"' or oldrefrenceno='"+a+"' ";   
}
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery(sql);
```

Comment: so what is the exception that you are catching?

Comment: Why you cast the siteid.getText() from string to int and then add it to a string again?

Comment: Constructing query with string concatenation is a bad practice, as it allows [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use [prepared statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

Comment: without try catch i found this exception :

String a=txt_search.getText();
String sql ="select * from account WHERE siteid ="+a+" or refrenceno='"+a+"' or oldrefrenceno='"+a+"' ";
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery(sql);

YOU ARE RIGHT IT WORKED

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search based on three fields then your query should be as

```
sql ="select * from account WHERE siteid ="+s+" AND refrenceno='"+a+"' AND oldrefrenceno='"+a+"' ";
```

Comment: no i just want to search data based on three columns of account.textfield is one

Comment: can you give the description of the table

Comment: THANKS EVERY ONE PROBLEM HAS BEEN SOLVED